# Travelling through UK - H1B (Visa stamp expired) but have a UK visitor's visa

Tags: transit, uk, indian-citizens, h1b-visas

I am an Indian citizen. I am going to India on a vacation. I am planning to have my flight via London. I've a layover there at London for almost 5-6 hours. I have a visitor's visa for UK but not planning to visit the city this time, my concern is that my H1 stamp on my passport has expired.

Can I pass through London with expired US visa stamp on my passport as I have UK visitor's visa on my passport?

Comment: Interesting point! Can an entry clearance be used as an exemption document? It's a 'gap' in the rules.  My guess is that it's ok because it's reasonable, but strictly by the book the answer is no.  Very interesting question!

Comment: If you have a visitor's visa, unless it is a used single-entry visa, you do not need a transit visa.  Why would you?